# How far in advance should I inform my boss that I'm taking a week off?

Tags: vacation

I'll be taking a week off for vacation, how far in advance should I inform my manager about this?

Comment: What did your boss say when you asked him?

Comment: I haven't asked him yet. My question is about WHEN I should ask him.

Comment: No I meant "What did he say when you asked him how far in advance you should ask for vacation?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it in bad taste to take a week off a job I began only a month ago?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48976/is-it-in-bad-taste-to-take-a-week-off-a-job-i-began-only-a-month-ago)

Comment: Note: usually you don't **inform** your boss that you are taking a week off, you **ask** him for a week off. In almost all legislations, the employer may deny your chosing (unless it is for reasons like wedding, a family member death/illness) etc., if it affects negatively the work schedule. So you should ask him ASAP so he could schedule production if necessary.

Comment: @NotMe, it is clearly not a duplicate. "May I ask for" and "When should I ask" are different concerns.

To those who have voted to close, can you explain why this is off-topic? Even if some companies or jobs might have specific rules, I see this question as a general question of professionalism which can applies to most companies I know.

Answer (score 10):

**As soon as you know it.**

First reason, **for your manager** :

- It helps your manager to organize the team planning, and to know in advance when there will be few people available in the team.

Second & third reasons, **for you** :

- If many other colleagues have scheduled holidays at the same date, it's often the "first arrived, first served" rule. Telling him asap increase your chances to have vacation the week you want to. If he wants to plan something for you (training, meeting with a client or whatever...), he can also take your request on consideration, but only if you made the request before.
- If you tell him soon, he will approve your vacation soon, and so you can reserve you hotel, plane whatever at the best price.

Comment: And ask for the time off before you make reservations if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should be written in your employee handbook. If not, ask HR if your company has specific rules regarding it. Or just ask your manager right now.