# Is it in bad taste to take a week off a job I began only a month ago?

Tags: conferences

I'll be starting my first job out of college soon. However, one of my professors from college and I agreed that I should attend a conference where I published a paper and present it. The problem is that this conference is only about a month after I begin my job. I also have to be at the conference for the entire week since it is in a much further country than where I will work and I have to present on Monday and Friday, so I basically have to be at the conference for the whole week.

How far ahead should I inform my manager about this and what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You've already asked this question. If you want to add extra information to a previous question, you can edit it.

Comment: Could you ask the organisers if your presentations could be on the same day, or a day apart? Taking a couple of days off shouldn't be much of a deal.

Comment: No, the schedule of the conference is fixed.

Comment: Ideally, the need for a week off, if already known, should be discussed as part of the start date discussion. Employer: "Can you start on date X?", new employee: "Yes, but I have a prior commitment to talk at a conference week Y." Too late for this to be an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Tell them before you start that you have this conference planned and the dates and ask them if you can attend. Likely they will give you time off without pay as you haven't earned any vacation time yet.  But most places are unlikely to tell you that you can't go be a speaker at a conference that was set up before you started working for them.